# Changing theme in android project in eclipse

Tags: android, themes

I'm having a problem with finding where I can change my project's theme.
For now, I'm learning android using [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html).

My project's theme looks like this:
[image]

And I'd like this UI looked like that:

[image]

Where can I find that theme and instructions, to install it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The theme you are looking for is Holo, either Holo Light or Holo Dark. There are multiple variations of this theme so make sure to play with the themes until you find the one you need.
In order to use this theme in your xml file use this as a parameter for the  tag:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

There are many more variations of Holo, which would be in the style

```
Theme.Holo.insertvariationshere
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the themes xml file at the link below. Scroll to the bottom and you will see a link to the xml file that is used for themes. You can look through this for reference but it should have already become available to you when you downloaded the SDK.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

In order to change the theme, you just modify your manifest file

```
<application android:theme="@style/[themeNameHere]">
```