# Why is my android app "black theme"?

Tags: android, android-activity, emulation

I was just working around and then when I tried in the emulator the app looked like this? 
Does anyone know what the problem is?
Link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97063669/black.png

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19849308/1848929

Comment: That guy wants to have the theme i am having,i don't want that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In values folder create file styles.xml and create theme inside:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
```

Create folder values-v11 in it create file styles.xml also create theme inside so it looks like this:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
```

Finally in the manifest, declare the theme:

```
android:theme="@style/myTheme"
```

Comment: Well, that does not change anything :/

Comment: Could you please post your manifest

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97063669/theme.png  I am a noob btw ;)

Comment: After the <Aplication> remove the > and put it after the theme

Comment: Also remove the > from the end of the android:label line

Comment: requires api level 11 (current min is 8). the  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" code is underlined red

Comment: Please see my edit. It should solve your problem. Let me know if it helps you.